# How to define amazing Goodstein's sequence?

Tags: equation-solving, integer-sequence

There is an amazing and  counterintuitive  theorem:

> For all $n$, there exists a $k$ such that the $k$-th term of the [Goodstein sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoodsteinSequence.html) $G_k(n)=0$. In other words, every Goodstein sequence converges to $0$.

I want to do something like this :

define Goodstein sequence `G[k,n]` then

```
DiscretePlot[G[k, n], {k, 1, N}]
```

and

How can I find $N$ such $G_{N}(n)=0$?

I tried first few steps:

following code is from [wolfram demonstrations project](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/HereditaryRepresentation/).

```
h[list_] := Select[MapIndexed[{#1, Length[list] - First[#2]} &,list], #[[1]] > 0 &]

patrList[n_, b_] := Map[f[#, b] &, h[IntegerDigits[n, b]]]

rule[b_] := {a_Integer, c_} -> t[a, p[b, c]]

f[{a_, c_}, b_] := If[c > b, {a, patrList[c, b]}, {a, c}]

ruleHold = n_Integer -> HoldForm[n];

rules = {t[1, c_] -> c, p[n_, 0] -> 1, p[n_, 1] -> n, t[a_, 1] -> a};

patrForm[n_, b_] :=patrList[n, b] //. rule[b] //. rules /. ruleHold //. 
 t[x_, y_] -> Times[x, y] //. List -> Plus //.  p[x_, y_] -> Power[x, y] // TraditionalForm
```

then

$G_1(10)=$ `patrForm[10, 2]`

$G_2(10)=$ `(patrForm[10, 2] /. {2 -> 3}) - 1`

> $\textbf{Definition}$  The Goodstein Function $g(n)$ is deﬁned to be the smallest  number $k$ for which $G_{k}(n)=0$.

Here are the ﬁrst few values of the function $g(n)$.see [here](https://andrescaicedo.files.wordpress.com/2008/04/goodstein.pdf)

$$g(0)=1$$
$$g(1)=2$$
$$g(2)=4$$
$$g(3)=6$$
$$g(4)=6.895\times10^{121210694}$$

Comment: Your pressing problem is how to compute a "hereditary representation"; after that, getting a Goodstein sequence is not too hard.

Comment: @J.M. see [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/HereditaryRepresentation/)

Comment: I already looked at that; my point was that you need to compute such a representation first, probably starting with the output of `IntegerDigits[]`.

Answer (score 2):

The `patrForm` function from the Wolfram demonstrations example really produces the hereditary representation of a number, so now all we have to do is to apply it a given number of times, subtracting 1 in between:

```
nextGoodstein[{h_, nb_}] := {patrForm[ReleaseHold[h /. {nb - 1 -> nb}] - 1, nb], nb + 1};
goodsteinHeld[k_, n_] := First@Nest[nextGoodstein, {patrForm[n, 2], 3}, k];
goodstein[k_, n_] := ReleaseHold[goodsteinHeld[k, n]];
goodsteinListHeld[k_, n_] := First /@ NestList[nextGoodstein, {patrForm[n, 2], 3}, k];
goodsteinList[k_, n_] := ReleaseHold[goodsteinListHeld[k, n]];
goodsteinFunction[num_] := Last@NestWhile[nextGoodstein, {patrForm[num, 2], 3}, Positive[ReleaseHold[First[#]]] &] - 2;

Table[goodsteinFunction[num], {num, 0, 3}]
goodsteinListHeld[50, 4]
goodsteinList[50, 4]
```

However, this won't allow to compute `goodsteinFunction[4]`, of course.
Also, don't change `num` to `n` here: it can cause identifier conflict and wrong results.